# Possible to create an app on Windows Phone (WP) using Visual Studio 2022 or later

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2022

**If the answer to my question is no, just say it and I'll mark this question as resolved/closed**. Otherwise, how can I attempt to write code to **Windows Phone (WP) mobile OS** using **Visual Studio 2022 or later**?

Why you may ask? Curiosity and my desire to learn.

What I've attempted:

- Running Windows Mobile SDK 8.0 (It doesn't work.)

Miscellaneous info:

- OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
- VS info: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - (Planning to downgrade to Microsoft Visual Studio Community later. If done, will it still work?)
- VS version: 17.5.5

Comment: Maybe you need to do some digging on Area51: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383855/the-windows-phone-se-site-has-been-archived or have a look at https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic  but for starters it might help if you include what "doesn't work" mean. Errors? Failed to run? Couldn't install? Fried your motherboard? Made coffee instead?

Comment: Ok, I'll keep it in mind. Also, the error on the SDK is: Unable to locate "VS_PreClean_WPexpress.exe". Verbose: Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Pre-Clean Tool Not Found (404). Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: I was unable to find anything useful to my question on the sites mentioned by @rene

Comment: You will not find many users today that want to do what you do. Maybe https://superuser.com/questions/1469284/can-not-install-visual-studio-ultimate-2012 helps as you obviously have some dependencies issues. One final option might be figure out what the MSI is that insists on running VS_PreClean_WPexpress.exe and then edit the MSI with Orca and remove that clean-up tool and then try again. But don't expect an answer here that will talk you through that process as it is extremely fiddely and probably brings you more troubles further down the road.